Late binding in VB.net and a "last chance" method?
I have several (very old and code frozen) VB.Net class libraries that have dozens of classes derived from a single base class, cBaseRow. The subclasses are mostly collections of properties that call GetValue in cBaseRow, providing O-R mapping to an .xls file. So one can:
Dim N As Double = myRentRow.RentValue

RentValue calls GetValue("RentValue") on cBaseRow and .TryParses it to a Double. Simple stuff.
There is another class called NoteRow which is accessed through a similar method on cBaseRow:
Public Function GetNote(Tab As String, Row as Integer, Field As String) As String

... so you can retrieve the note on any field with something like:
Dim N as String = myRentRow. GetNote("Rent", myRentRow.RowNum, "RentValue")

The original libraries do not include properties for these values. I would like to add them...
Dim N as String = myRentRow.RentValueNote

I know I can implement methods on the existing library using extensions. But there are many dozens of classes with dozens of fields, and the library is used in dozens of projects with different subclasses.
My question: is there is a way in VB to implement a method on the base class that will "catch" such calls?
For instance, in Obj-C I could override the objc_msgSend method in cBaseRow and any method call that isn't implemented will fall into this method with the method call as a string.
Is there any similar functionality in .Net?
Or is there another way to implement this?

There's [CallerMemberName] that does more or less the same thing: the associated string value returns the name of the calling Method or Property. You can pass whatever other value to a proxy -- BTW, it's not clear what's wrong with extension methods. You can access internal Fields / Properties / Methods of the class you're extending

Besides that, you have ConditionalWeakTable, ExpandoObjects, Roslyn's Emit()  method etc.

@Jimi - there is nothing "wrong" with extensions, it's just there is going to be a lot of them and different ones across a bunch of projects. The CMN appears to work only if the caller is a known method, but I'm going to try that to see.

there is going to be a lot of them and different ones across a bunch of projects: there's probably something I'm missing here. Don't you just need to extend cBaseRow, to then access the extension methods from derived classes?

@Jimi - sorry, didn't get a notification for some reason. Maybe I'm just thinking about it wrong, but the base class does not have properties, the data is like a dictionary with string keys. It is the subclasses that add properties that look up the data from the collection. So there might be an item keyed "RentValue" in the dictionary and the subclass has a property called RentValue that returns it. There are many of these, and I would like to add another property to each subclass for every existing property.

Well, extension Properties still don't exist, so you're stuck with extension methods (properties are actually get_PropName(), set_PropName() methods under the hood, if this detail makes you feel better), or one of the relatively complicated and non-hassle-free tools previously listed

To your direct question "Is there any similar functionality in .NET" the answer is "No".  You might implement it as an extension method requiring to manually specify the string, though.  CallerMemberName sorta kinda gets you part of the way there, but it still requires starting out with a real implemented routine.

With the manual string method, on the implementation side, you could even use reflection to have it automatically pick up an existing member, which would be a bit hacky but would work.  Just beware that reflection is usually very slow, so it's not a good idea for anything performance-critical.

@Craig - thanks, save me time beating my head on this!

@MauryMarkowitz Upon further consideration, I think it's worth turning my comments into an answer, so I did so.

To your direct question "Is there any similar functionality in .NET" the answer is "No".
An alternative that would get you most of the way there would be to make something like late-binding or reflection where you make an extension method taking a string argument (and possibly a ParamArray or an explicit array of arguments).  You could even use this a little like a reverse of the Obj-C version and use reflection to look for existing members on the actual type.  I could see two drawbacks to this approach: First, as with late-binding, if you have a signature problem (name or type/count of parameters) it will show up at runtime instead of compile time; second, reflection is notoriously slow, so you would want to memo-ize as much as possible and avoid doing it on a performance-critical path.
